# ¿Cómo resolver errores en procesos aritméticos en Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

Durante las pruebas de la interfaz gráfica siguiente, encuentro que presenta muchos errores a la hora de determinar el salario neto de una persona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, en este caso el salario neto debería ser de 900000, sin embargo, figura en números negativos. La porción de código correspondiente es esta:

```
sueldo = self.ui.TxtSueldo.toPlainText()

extra = self.ui.TxtExtra.toPlainText()

sueldo= int(sueldo)

extra=int(extra)

ips=sueldo*0.10

pago1= 15000*extra

pago2=20000*extra

caja=sueldo*0.30

ausencias= self.ui.TxtCantidadAusencias.toPlainText()

ausencias= int(ausencias)

unitario= sueldo/30

ausenciastotales=sueldo-(unitario*ausencias)

if self.ui.RdbDiurno.isChecked():

    self.ui.TxtPago.setText(str(pago1))
    neto= sueldo+pago1


else:

    self.ui.TxtPago.setText(str(pago2))
    neto= sueldo+pago2



if self.ui.ChkIps.isChecked():

    self.ui.TxtIps.setText(str(ips))


if self.ui.ChkCaja.isChecked():

    self.ui.TxtCaja.setText(str(caja))


if self.ui.ChkAusencias.isChecked():


    self.ui.TxtAusencias.setText(str(unitario))




neto= sueldo+pago1+pago2-ips-caja-ausenciastotales
self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))
```

P.D.: Los textboxes donde deben introducirse valores enteros inicializan en 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un problema con la GUI, son fallos de lógica al calcular cada cosa. Te recomiendo siempre dar nombres lo más descriptivos que puedas a cada variable, esto hace el código más legible para ti y para terceros, facilitando mucho seguir la lógica del mismo.

El principal problema es que calculas todos los egresos e ingresos pero no tienes en cuenta si se deben aplicar o no según lo seleccionado.

Además, a la hora de comprobar el rango horario de las extra, calculas dentro de los condicionales `neto= sueldo+pago1` / `neto= sueldo+pago2`, pero ese cálculo lo desestimas luego ya que reasignas a neto al final.

El código debería quedar algo así:

```
# Calculamos ingresos
sueldo = float(self.ui.TxtSueldo.toPlainText())
horas_extra = float(self.ui.TxtExtra.toPlainText())
if self.ui.RdbDiurno.isChecked():
    sueldo_extra = 15000 * horas_extra
else:
    sueldo_extra = 20000 * horas_extra

# Calculamos egresos
egreso_ips = 0
egreso_caja = 0
egreso_ausencias = 0

if self.ui.ChkIps.isChecked():
    egreso_ips = sueldo * 0.10

if self.ui.ChkCaja.isChecked():
    egreso_caja = sueldo * 0.30

if self.ui.ChkAusencias.isChecked():
    ausencias = int(self.ui.TxtCantidadAusencias.toPlainText())
    egreso_ausencias = (sueldo / 30) * ausencias

# Calculamos el sueldo neto
neto = sueldo + sueldo_extra - egreso_ips - egreso_caja - egreso_ausencias

# Actualizamos valores de cada Text
self.ui.TxtPago.setText(str(sueldo_extra))
self.ui.TxtIps.setText(str(egreso_ips))
self.ui.TxtCaja.setText(str(egreso_caja))
self.ui.TxtAusencias.setText(str(egreso_ausencias))
self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))
```

No entra dentro de la pregunta, pero si no lo has hecho ya deberías validar las entradas de sueldo, horas extra y ausencias para evitar que el usuario pueda ingresar cosas que no debe y terminar con resultados erróneos o con una excepción y el cierre de la app directamente.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator, QDoubleValidator

# En inicializador de la clase o opcionalmente en QtDesigner
self.ui.TxtSueldo.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0, float("inf"), 2, self))
self.ui.TxtExtra.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0, 999, 2, self))
self.ui.TxtCantidadAusencias.setValidator(QIntValidator(0, 99, self))
```

Las demás entradas deberían ser de solo lectura (`entry.setReadOnly(True)`) o no ser un widget de entrada  sino solo para mostrar datos como `TextBrowser`.

Comment: ¿Y cómo podría realizar la validación del close? Es decir, que tire un mensaje al estilo "¿Está seguro de que desea cerrar esta ventana?"